# Is it possible to use a regexp to fetch sheets name that are use in QUERY function (range)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i'm currently working on a "search" sheet *(it's just a query function with multiple sheets range)*. It works great, but there is one thing that concerns me, I want to automate it so that I don't have to come back to it every time a new sheet is created.

**Here is my query function:**

`=QUERY({'type - sheetName'!A4:E;'type - sheetName2'!A4:E;};"SELECT * WHERE (LOWER(Col2) CONTAINS """&MINUSCULE(C1)&""" OR LOWER(Col4) CONTAINS """&LOWER(C1)&""")";-1)`

**So my question is this :**

Is it possible to add sheets in the range automatically (for example, if `type - sheetNameX` is created, it's added to the query's range list *(and also remove if the sheet is removed (not hidden))*?

I think a JS script can do it, but I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my testing and research, I'm unable to find a way to automatically add sheet names in the QUERY function range without using Apps Script.

**Recommendation**

With that being said, I've created a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) with a custom function `customQuery()` that uses [getSheetName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetname) method to get all of the sheet names on a spreadsheet (excluding the 'search' sheet), then it places the names to an array. After that, the code will format the `=QUERY()` function to contain the current sheet names and their ranges. You may refer to the info below for reference:

**Code**

```
/**
 * Custom function to add current sheet names and their ranges to the QUERY function
 */

function onOpen() { //[Optional] Created this custom menu to manually run the customQuery function to refresh the QUERY on the search sheet
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Refresh Query')
      .addItem('Refresh', 'customQuery')
      .addToUi();
}

function customQuery(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets();
  var sheetNames = []; //To contain all of the sheet names on your Spreadsheet
  var text = ""; //To contain all current sheet names on your Spreadsheet, except for 'search' sheet and to be formatted to be used in the QUERY function later
  for(var x=0; x<sheet.length;x++){
    if(sheet[x].getSheetName() != "search"){ //Will not include 'search' sheet
      sheetNames[x] = sheet[x].getSheetName();
    }
  }
  var lastIndex = sheetNames.length-1;
    for(var x=0; x<sheetNames.length;x++){ //check every sheet names and format it for the QUERY function
      if(x==0 ){ //First sheet name will have '{' at the beginning
        text = text + "{\'"+sheetNames[x]+'\'!A4:E;';
      }else{
        if(x != lastIndex){ //Sheets names inside the last & end sheet names will have ';' at the end of each names
          text = text + "\'"+sheetNames[x]+'\'!A4:E;';
        }else{ //Last sheet name will not have ';' but '}' sign at the end
          text = text + "\'"+sheetNames[x]+'\'!A4:E}';
        }
      }
    }
    var show = "=QUERY("+text+",\"SELECT * where Col1 <>''\")"; //Created this test query as I'm unable to replicate your original query on my end
    var version2 = "=QUERY("+text+",\"SELECT * WHERE (LOWER(Col2) CONTAINS \"\"\"&MINUSCULE(C1)&\"\"\" OR LOWER(Col4) CONTAINS \"\"\"&LOWER(C1)&\"\"\")\";-1)";
    Logger.log("Sample Query Function:\n" + show); //If you want to check your execution logs
    Logger.log("Original Query Function:\n"+version2); //If you want to check your execution logs
    ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('search!A1').setValue(show); // You can replace the value from 'show' to 'version2' on the .setValue() to use your original QUERY function.
}
```

***Note**:*

For some reason, I'm unable to replicate your actual query, specifically on this part,`"SELECT * WHERE (LOWER(Col2) CONTAINS """&MINUSCULE(C1)&""" OR LOWER(Col4) CONTAINS """&LOWER(C1)&""")";-1)`, so I've use a simple query on my end. However, you can replace my test query with your original query on the code on the setValue() line to test it on your actual spreadsheet.

**Test Sheets I've Used**

Test sheet "type - sheetName":

[image]

Test sheet "type - sheetName2":

[image]

Test sheet "type - sheetName3":

[image]

**Result**

After running the code, this will be the result on my test 'search' sheet, the QUERY will be placed on the cell A1:

[image]

**Additional Info**

If you prefer not to manually refresh your QUERY function, you can create a [time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers), like this one that I've created to run `customQuery` every 1 minute:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was very informative and greatly explained!